# Device manager sees my nano as FT232 USB UART not as COM port

Tags: arduino-nano, ide, ftdi

Until yesterday I had 2 arduino nanos (atmega328, 16Mhz, 5V), and they worked fine,when  I changed the cable and was able to upload code to them. Then I tried to make a breadboard arduino, but my PC (win8.1) was unable to see my FDTI 232RL USB2Serial converter as a COMPORT, so I tried to download drivers but nothing worked out.Anyway I decided to reinstall windows and now one of my Nano works just fine, but the Other appears as a FT232 USB UART at the device manager,so I stepped back... Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Are they genuine Arduinos?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams may be related: http://hackaday.com/2014/10/22/watch-that-windows-update-ftdi-drivers-are-killing-fake-chips/

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin: Hence the question.

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered me, the hackaday post solved my problem. I was able to unbrick my nano-clones.Now they work just fine.